# Why commonly Java Repository/Library is stored using Maven?

Tags: java, maven, gradle

Currently I'm learning the details about Gradle. I'm just curious, there is central repository like MavenCentral, and there are many repositories stored in there. It seems there are no 'GradleCentral', do all Java Library is usually using Maven as a build tools? If yes, why does this happen? Is it because of Maven is the better choice to create a Java library?

Comment: `It seems there are no 'GradleCentral'` Maven came before Gradle. Gradle developer choose to just use this huge repository of already existing libraries instead of inventing their own. Thats about it.

Comment: When artifacts reach maven central they are just collections of classes for putting on a classpath.  It is irrelevant how they were created.

Answer (score 3):

It's not just Maven Central that is available to host libraries. There are tons of public and private options out there but by far Maven Central is the most popular and safe option. For closed source development projects, libraries are hosted on nexus and other similar solutions and I've seen open source projects hosting on others as well.

As for the popularity of Maven, It is an official Apache project thus enjoys more authenticity over other similar build solutions and others show compatibility towards Maven as well.